# Out of memory onPress TouchableOpacity, React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a component where I display a button when certain conditions are met (based on component state)

```
{
      this.state.inputTag !== null && this.state.inputTagFocused ? (
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style = {{backgroundColor : Colors.primary, padding : 15, paddingBottom : 5, paddingTop : 5, borderRadius: 2}}
          onPress = {this.handleAddTags}
        >
          <Text style = {{fontFamily : Fonts.primary, color : Colors.white}}>Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : null
    }
```

Using TextInput component I am updating the state like this

```
<TextInput
  style = {{ borderBottomColor : Colors.grey, padding : 15, paddingLeft :0, paddingRight : 0, marginRight : 15}}
  onChange = {(text)=> this.setState({inputTag : text})}
  onFocus = {() => this.setState({inputTagFocused : true})}
  placeholderTextColor = {Colors.grey}
  ref = {(tags) => {this.tags = tags}}
  underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
  placeholder = 'Add Tags'
  returnKeyType = 'done'
  multiline = {false}
/>
```

Everything seems to work except when I press the add button the whole app crashes  and after few minutes I get the error of 'out of memory'.

What is causing the issue? and how can I solve it?

the full code can be found **[here](https://snack.expo.io/@tufailra97/onpress-issue-rn)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing , with + in your console.log()

Comment: But that should't be an issue, in fact I am passing a separate argument and I always did like that.